# How to find duplicated values from a 2d array (of 10x2) horizontally in c

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

I am trying to create a BattleShip game in c. In my case i want to save the ships cordinates into the Ship[10][2] array. So i want to find if there is any duplicated cordinate.
Imagin having this cordinates into Ships[10][2]

```
X 0 1
0 1,2
1 4,5
2 8,3
3 9,0
4 5,7
5 9,0
6 3,4
7 5,6
8 4,3
9 3,4
```

obviously the 9,0 and 3,4 is duplicated! I want to find it and show a message like this:

```
printf("\n\n\n---------------[WARNING]----------------------\n");
printf("There are more than 1 ships on x=%d y=%d !!",[variablex],[variabley]);
printf("\n---------------[WARNING]----------------------\n\n\n");
```

Need help. My example code is this but not showing correctly because showing more things and not only the dublicated values:

```c
for (i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
  for (j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
    if (Ships[i][0] == Ships[j][0]) { //topothesies x
      for (a=0; a<N-1; a++) {
        for (b=a+1; b<N; b++) {
          if (Ships[a][1] == Ships[b][1]) {
            printf("\n\n\n---------------[WARNING]----------------------\n");
            printf("Yparxoyn pano apo 1 karavia sto shmeio x=%d y=%d !!",
                   Ships[j][0],Ships[b][1]);
            printf("\n---------------[WARNING]----------------------\n\n\n");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I tried to answer your question, you should [edit] the question and create a [mre]. You should add enough code to allow us to compile and run it. Also show the input and actual output and the expected output. To simplify the program and the test you could fill the array with hard-coded values as shown in your example instead of requiring manual input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains 4 nested loops. The outer 2 loops compare the X coordinate of all pairs of rows, the inner 2 loops compare the Y coordinate independently from the outer loops.

But you don't want to find a pair that has the same X value and an independent pair that has the same Y value, but one pair that has **both** the same X values and the same Y values.

Something like this

```
for (i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
  for (j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
    if ((Ships[i][0] == Ships[j][0]) &&
        (Ships[i][1] == Ships[j][1]))
    {
      printf("\n\n\n---------------[WARNING]----------------------\n");
      printf("Yparxoyn pano apo 1 karavia sto shmeio x=%d y=%d !!",
                Ships[j][0], Ships[j][1]);
      printf("\n---------------[WARNING]----------------------\n\n\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on how the user will enter the values, it might be better to check for duplicates just after the user entered the coordinates for a ship and request new input for this single ship if a duplicate was found. With this solution you would need only a single loop for the check, embedded in an outer loop for the data input.

Comment: Ow yea now it works. My result: https://prnt.sc/vz9w2f
Thanks a lot sir!